# How to upload JS & CSS file changes to pre-optimized-min media library items

Tags: sxa, sxa-cli

I have an existing SXA project with a custom theme, in my local machine.
I have made changes in the `gallery.js` file.

**Path:** `D:\Projects\External\MyProject\theme\-\media\Themes\MyProject\Shared\Shared Theme\scripts\components\gallery.js`

**Changes:**

[image]

Then I executed these commands - `sxa build Js` & `sxa upload Js`.

[image]

I'm expecting the changes to go into the CMS item - `/sitecore/media library/Themes/MyProject/Shared/Shared Theme/Scripts/pre-optimized-min`, but unfortunately they didn't.

[image]

What is the correct way to push script/css changes into the CMS item.

Using Sitecore 10.1.3

Answer (score 1):

You can disable minification and debugging to see if your JS updates reflect correctly.

To change the optimization settings for a specific site. In the Content Editor, navigate to `sitecore/content/<Tenant>/<Site>/Presentation/Page Designs`.

In the Asset Optimization section, in the Styles Optimizing Enabled and Scripts Optimizing Enabled fields, to override styles and scripts optimization settings, select:

- Default – to inherit global settings
- Yes – to always enable optimization for this site.
- No – to always disable optimization for this site.

[image]

Select `Script Optimisation Enabled` to `No` and try again to validate it.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I set `Scripts Optimising Enabled` to `No`. But `sxa build Js` still says `Js Minification Done`. Executing `sxa upload Js` after that has no change when `pre-optimized.min.js` loads on page.